# split by comma and ignore if comma in quotes a data from List of Tuples - Python

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I have a list of tuples.

```
lt = [('051623', 'O143', '1.23', '2023-05-16T18:30:00', '1M allen', 'millan'), ('051623', 'O207', '1.23', '2023-05-16T18:35:00', 'nM Mn, 4nM, 35uM Fe', 'wilo')]
```

Need to convert to csv string by comma separated but while split the commas within quotes to be ignored: Expected is below.

```
'051623','O143','1.23','2023-05-16T18:30:00','1M allen','millan'
'051623', 'O207', '1.23', '2023-05-16T18:35:00','nM Mn, 4nM, 35uM Fe','wilo'
```

I tried but not working:

```
csv_string = '\n'.join(",".join([element if element else 'None' for element in tup]) for tup in lt)
```

Comment: Are you going to write the final string to a file, or it's just an experiment?

Comment: I am writing to a csv file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `csv` library:

```py
lt = [
  ('051623', 'O143', '1.23', '2023-05-16T18:30:00', '1M allen', 'millan'), 
  ('051623', 'O207', '1.23', '2023-05-16T18:35:00', 'nM Mn, 4nM, 35uM Fe', 'wilo'),
]

import io
import csv


# Allows saving the csv output to a string instead of a file
f = io.StringIO(newline='')    

writer = csv.writer(
    f,
    quotechar="'",
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
)
writer.writerows(lt)

# `getvalue()` returns a string containing the csv output
print(f.getvalue())
```

It outputs

```
'051623','O143','1.23','2023-05-16T18:30:00','1M allen','millan'
'051623','O207','1.23','2023-05-16T18:35:00','nM Mn, 4nM, 35uM Fe','wilo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```py
s = '\n'.join([','.join([f"'{y}'" for y in x]) for x in lt])
```

Output

```
'051623','O143','1.23','2023-05-16T18:30:00','1M allen','millan'
'051623','O207','1.23','2023-05-16T18:35:00','nM Mn, 4nM, 35uM Fe','wilo'
```

Additionally, you'll want to escape any single quotation-marks within the text.

```py
s = '\n'.join([','.join([f"'{y}'" for y in [z.replace("'", r"\'") for z in x]]) for x in lt])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to recompose the lines as csv data without actually writing to CSV, you can use the following, which will wrap every individual value in double quotes

```py
lines=[]
for tup in lt:
    lines.append('"' + '","'.join(tup)+'"')

print(lines)
# [
# '"051623","O143","1.23","2023-05-16T18:30:00","1M allen","millan"',
# '"051623","O207","1.23","2023-05-16T18:35:00","nM Mn, 4nM, 35uM Fe","wilo"'
# ]
```

Or if you only want to wrap the cells that contain commas:

```
lines=[]
for tup in lt:
    line=''
    for el in tup:
        if ',' in el:
            el = '"'+el+'"'
        line += el + ','
    lines.append(line[:-1]) # Strip the extra , at the end

print(lines)
# [
#   '051623,O143,1.23,2023-05-16T18:30:00,1M allen,millan',
#   '051623,O207,1.23,2023-05-16T18:35:00,"nM Mn, 4nM, 35uM Fe",wilo'
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

My code iterates through the list `lt`, formats each element in the tuples by adding single quotes around them, and joins them with commas. as specified in the your question:

```py
lt = [
    ("051623", "O143", "1.23", "2023-05-16T18:30:00", "1M allen", "millan"),
    ("051623", "O207", "1.23", "2023-05-16T18:35:00", "nM Mn, 4nM, 35uM Fe", "wilo"),
]
for words in lt:
    formatted_words = []
    for word in words:
        formatted_word = "'{}'".format(word)
        formatted_words.append(formatted_word)
    formatted_lt = ",".join(formatted_words)
    print(formatted_lt)
```